# python script embedded in C++ not running 2nd time onwards in a loop

Tags: python, embedding

I am trying to embed a python script into my C++ application. The script will import h5py, numpy, Tensorflow etc. and will be called multiple times in a loop within the program. The problem is: script is executed first time and is not executed in further iterations. The C++ snippet is:

```
#include "python2.7/Python.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        PyObject *pName = NULL;
        PyObject *pModule=NULL;

        string path = "/path/to/my/scripts/";
        PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
        string str = "sys.path.append('" + path + "')";

        PyRun_SimpleString(str.c_str());
        cout<<"imported sys "<<endl;

        cout<<"i = "<<i<<endl;
        pName = PyUnicode_FromString("pytest");
        if (pName)
        cout<<"pName is fine "<<pName<<endl;

        pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
        if (pModule)
        cout<<"pModule is fine"<<pModule<<endl;

        Py_DECREF(pName);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
    }
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

This program tries to run the following script: pytest.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import glob
import h5py
import numpy as np
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

print('Hello World')
f = h5py.File('/path/to/h5/file/file.hdf5','r')
print(str(f['dataList']))
...
```

I compile the C++ program using:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/python2.7 cpp_pytest.cc -lpython2.7
```

I do not see why the script does not run 2nd time in the loop where everything seems fine...The output of ./a.out is:

```
imported sys 
i = 0
pName is fine 0x7f84aa302210
Using TensorFlow backend.
Hello World
<HDF5 dataset "dataList": shape (716, 702), type "<f8">
pModule is fine0x7f84aa301408
imported sys 
i = 1
pName is fine 0x7f84aa302210
pModule is fine0x7f84aa301408
imported sys 
i = 2
pName is fine 0x7f84aa302210
pModule is fine0x7f84aa301408
```

Can anyone point me to what is going on here? Your valuable suggestion is highly appreciated. I am sure that the .py script has not been touched at all the 2nd/3rd time.

Regards,
Kolahal

Comment: Just like `import` in Python, `PyImport_Import` won’t rerun a module’s code.  You can’t use it to run *scripts*.  Could you make the relevant code a function that C++ can invoke repeatedly?